# The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Connection closed - Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I've been stuck on this for a few weeks and I've run out of ideas.

I am trying to move two Ruby sites to a new server. One is working flawlessly and the other gives the Connection closed error.

It should be a standard Apache + Passenger 3.0 + Ruby 1.8.7 + Rails 2.3.18 setup.
Both Ruby sites are based on the same code with slight differences.
I'm also not a Ruby guy, I just administer the servers however the developers are out of ideas on this issue.

Apache's error log with Passenger debugging turned to maximum shows this:

```
[ pid=23816 thr=139877253064448 file=ext/common/ApplicationPool/Pool.h:939 time=2013-05-15 14:19:28.87 ]: Spawning a process for /home/xxxxx because there are none for this app group
[ pid=23816 thr=139877253064448 file=ext/common/ApplicationPool/../SpawnManager.h:289 time=2013-05-15 14:19:28.88 ]: Spawning a new application process for /home/xxxxx...
[ pid=23816 thr=139877253064448 file=ext/common/ApplicationPool/Server.h:292 time=2013-05-15 14:19:34.141 ]: Client 28: SpawnException occured (with error page)
```

So it tries to spawn the app and it fails. I can't locate any logs which explain why it is failing however.

Running ./script/server from the app's root folder works fine so everything must be more or less working correctly with the app.

The Apache config file is pretty straight forward and fairly basic: (simplified slightly)

```
PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
PassengerEnabled off
PassengerUserSwitching on
PassengerLogLevel 3
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName xxxxx.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@agentpoint.com.au
        DocumentRoot /home/xxxxx/public
        PassengerEnabled on
        PassengerAppRoot /home/xxxxx
        PassengerTempDir /home/xxxxx/tmp
        PassengerUploadBufferDir /home/xxxxx/tmp/uploads
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone know how this error could be occuring given the fact that a nearly identical code base works fine? And what logging should show a spawn error like that? I really am missing that crucial step that is failing and I can't figure out what it is doing precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Could you upgrade to Phusion Passenger 4? That would potentially solve your problem. If not, then Phusion Passenger 4 has much better error reporting. It will print the error reason to the logs.